# Draw a rectangle in the preview window in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I draw rectangles over the detected faces in the preview window in MATLAB? I have done a program in MATLAB for face detection and this program when it is running will take one frame and detect the face in that frame and draw circles over that face.  However, I need to draw rectangles in the preview window so that I can achieve a continuous face detection.  Can anybody give an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rectangle` command.  Assuming that the `figure` window is already open, you can call `rectangle` like so:

```
rectangle('Position', [x y w h]);
```

`x` and `y` denote the column and row co-ordinate of the top left corner of your rectangle.  `w,h` denote the width and height of the rectangle.  By default, this will draw a black rectangle.  If you want to change the line colour, you can do:

```
rectangle('Position', [x y w h], 'EdgeColor', 'c');
```

`c` would be a string of the colour you want (i.e. `'red', 'blue', 'yellow'`, etc.)

Hope this helps!